# vuejs - define v-model only when object exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My select box is working fine when the variable `item.ativo_retencao.id` exists correctly.

```
<select name="ativo_retencao" v-model="item.ativo_retencao.id" class="form-control m-input">
  <option v-for="ativo in ativos" v-bind:value="ativo.id">@{{ ativo.title }}</option>
</select>
```

So when it does not exists, I want to not define (or set null) the v-model property.

Is that possible?

Comment: And what behavior would it be when you can select an option and the selected option will not be saved at all?

Comment: @Anatoly Good question. It does not make sense to render select at all in this case...just use `v-if`

Answer (score 1):

you can use an ternary to do this:

```
<select name="ativo_retencao" :v-model="item.ativo_retencao.id ? item.ativo_retencao.id : ''" class="form-control m-input">
  <option v-for="ativo in ativos" v-bind:value="ativo.id">@{{ ativo.title }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it's causing `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' `

Comment: I don't think so ....`null` is not valid "left side" for assigment

Comment: and ''' is not either...try again

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` is just [syntactic sugar](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) (code below applies just for `select` element):

```html
v-model="item.ativo_retencao.id"
```

..is same as

```html
:value="item.ativo_retencao.id" v-on:change="item.ativo_retencao.id = $event.target.value"
```

...so if you don't have a value you want to bind to, just don't render the `select` at all

```html
<select v-if="item.ativo_retencao.id" name="ativo_retencao" :v-model="item.ativo_retencao.id" class="form-control m-input">
  <option v-for="ativo in ativos" v-bind:value="ativo.id">@{{ ativo.title }}</option>
</select>
```